# JS: Math.random for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, return, call

Learning JS this week.

Is it possible to use Math.random to return a random value in an array? Does that value be a string and still work?

Answer (score 24):

You can take the floating point number (between 0 and 1, non-inclusive) and convert it to an index to the array (integer between 0 and length of the array - 1). For example:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using rather longer statement strings in each array value. Is there a way to syntactically write this so it's not just one very large line?

Comment: It doesn't matter how do you construct the array. The important part is `floor(length_of_the_array * random_value_between_0_and_1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Read this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var r = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]; // r will store a value from a pseudo-random position at arr.
```

Comment: Math.round(Math.random()*a.length) can return a number that is equal to a.length, which is not a valid index to the array.

Comment: Kindly check its not a*length it will be arr.length

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is indeed possible.  Here's some example code:

```
<script>
    var arr = new Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
    document.write("Test " + arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * ((arr.length - 1) - 0 + 1))]);
</script>
```

Note that Math.floor should be used instead of Math.round, in order to get a uniform number distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help.

```
//My array was setup as such.
var arr = New Array();
arr[0]="Long string for value.";
arr[1]="Another long string.";
//etc...
```

With your help, and since I know the exact number of values in my array (2), I just did:

```
var randomVariable = arr[Math.floor(2*Math.random())]
```

Then output randomVariable how I wish.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use `arr.length`, not `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var array = [];
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
array[i] = Math.floor( Math.random() * 60 );
}
```

if you need a number between 1 and 100, just change Math.random() * 60 to Math.random() * 100.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is very possible to do what you're asking

```
const diceRoll = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => {
return i + 1;
});

console.log(Math.random() * diceRoll.length);
```

The code there, why it works is that Math.random returns a random number between 0 and whatever value we set and the value we set here is diceRoll.length which is 100 so it will return a random value between 0 and 99

```
console.log(Math.random() * diceRoll.length + 1);
```

will make it return random value between 0 and 100