# How to pick random in an array, then set a <p> element to that chosen phrase

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

its me. I'm working on a gift for my grandma for Christmas, and decided to make a poem generator. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? I don't know how and I cant find a reference so I haven't tried anything. Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516695/js-math-random-for-array) is most likely what you're after.

Comment: It is! Thanks a lot!